# Python Launcher preferences in mac OSX not allowing selection of python 3.6 interpreter

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

This problem is that when I run my python programs through python launcher python launcher tries to run it in python 2.7, causing the print command(?) to have brackets around them and numerous other broken things.

I downloaded Python Launcher with python 3.6 from the python.org website.

When opening Python Launcher > Preferences, the 'interpreter' drop-down field has the following options:

/usr/local/bin/pythonw

/usr/local/bin/python

/usr/bin/pythonw

/usr/bin/python

/sw/bin/pythonw

I don't know what the difference between python or pythonw is, or even what any of them mean, but no matter which one I select it always tries to run in python 2.7.

What makes it even more baffling to me is when choosing to open my script in IDLE it says right at the top: (python 3.6.3) and runs a window called 'Python 3.6.3 shell'

How can I get the program to run using python 3.6.3 through Python Launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and this is what I did to solve it.

First, go to Python Launcher > Preferences and check the box where it says "Allow override with #! in script". This way, you can specify in every script what is the python version you want to run the scripts you open with Python launcher.

Then, add this line as the first line of every python script you write:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

This line will tell Python Launcher that the script should run in Python 3.6. That should solve your problem.

Also, I'm new to Python, so I don't know if there are any problems with this solution, or if there's a simpler way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me with Python 3.7 installed on OS X Mojave. But simply changing the Interpreter to "python3" in the Python Launcher preferences solved the problem.